# How to get the text contains square brackets in square brackets?

Tags: c#, regex, square-bracket

I have a string like

```
string str = "[COUNT([Weight] > 10)] < 20 AND [COUNT([Height] < 10)] < 25";
```

And I want to get the value in square bracket. If I use expression Regex(`@"\[.*?\]"`) => it returns

```
[COUNT([Weight] and [COUNT([Height]
```

but I want to get the value

```
[COUNT([Weight] > 10)] and [COUNT([Height] < 10)]
```

Could I do that? Please assist me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about without regex?

```
string str = "[COUNT([Weight] > 10] < 20";
var start = str.IndexOf('[');
var end = str.LastIndexOf(']');
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(start, end - start + 1));
```

[image]

Comment: I like the IndexOf and going without Regex! +1

Comment: Your solution is well done in this case. But I have a string str="[COUNT([Weight] > 10 AND [Weight] > 5)] < 10". I would like to get the value [COUNT([Weight] > 10 AND [Weight] > 5)]

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex.

```
@"\[(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*\]"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN4oT1/2)

`(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*` (*Matches `[..]` block or any char but not of `[` or `]`* ) , zero or more times.

Comment: Accept an answer which helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
var pattern = @"\[.*\]";
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hV7zQ5/1)**